# How can I see entries of more than one day in Emacs calendar?

Tags: calendar, diary

I want to use the built in calender. 
In the Manual i found many key bindings for moving around in the calendar.
But for showing the entries / dates in my calender i found only "d", which shows me the entry of one day.

So, how can i see the entries of one week, month, year or perhaps a list of all entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your help.
What lawlist wrote ist what i'm looking for. But i need time to evaluate these informations.

The fast way is to export to HTML (H-...) or LaTeX (t-...).
All information about exporting the calendar file can be found in the Emacs Manual under "Writing Calendar Files"

Answer (score 3):

The built-in `calendar-mode` and `diary-mode` have their limitations.  However, `diary-mode` is designed to present a span of time if so desired.  Load the `diary-lib` library with `M-x eval-expression RET (require 'diary-lib) RET` and then type `M-x describe-function RET diary-list-entries RET` to read about it.  For more advanced searching and calendaring abilities, take a look at the built-in `org-mode` / `org-agenda-mode`, and `calfw` https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-calfw .  A quick grep of the Emacs built-in code revealed that the `cal-tex` library is designed to work with the diary feature, if you use TeX/LaTeX that is.

See also the function `diary`, which has a doc-string that states as follows:

```
"Generate the diary window for ARG days starting with the current date.
If no argument is provided, the number of days of diary entries is governed
by the variable `diary-number-of-entries'.  A value of ARG less than 1
does nothing.  This function is suitable for execution in an init file."
```

And, of course, the above doc-string mentioned that the variable `diary-number-of-entries` is customizable.

The function `diary-view-entries` also looks interesting, so check that out too:

```
"Prepare and display a buffer with diary entries.
Searches the file named in `diary-file' for entries that match
ARG days starting with the date indicated by the cursor position
in the displayed three-month calendar."
```

Answer (score 0):

Press `v` in agenda view to see all options.

To set the default view in number of days, set variable `org-agenda-span`.

Comment: The question is not about org-mode I think.

Comment: Mea culpa. I should be. :)